# I want to pass a array of url to button using map () function. but on button click i get object but it does not navigate me to exact page

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, http-redirect, buttonclick

Here is the code below I am storing URL in the object productsLink. But I have also made the button dynamically into the card there 4 different buttons and I want to navigate these 4 links on the button click

```
const productsLink = [
          {
            linkData: [
              { plink: "https://store.myshopify.com/products/gold-2" },
              {
                plink: "https://store.myshopify.com/products/white-gold-3",
              },
              {
                plink: "https://store.myshopify.com/products/gold-1",
              },
              {
                plink: "https://store.myshopify.com/products/silver",
              },
            ],
          },
        ];
        const productsLinkResul = productsLink.linkData.map((product) => (
          <span>{product.linkData.plink}</span>
        ));
        
        return(
        <div>
        <Button
         href={productsLinkResul}>shop</Button>
        </div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
const productsLinkResul = productsLink.linkData.map((product) => (
    <Button href={product.linkData.plink}>{product.linkData.plink}</span>
));

        
return(
 <div>
  {productsLinkResul}
</div>)
```

productsLink is array. so access from 0th index.

```
const productsLinkResul = productsLink[0]?.linkData.map((product) => (
    <Button href={product.linkData.plink}>{product.linkData.plink}</span>
));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
const productsLinkResul = productsLink[0].linkData.map((product) => (
    <Button href={product.plink}>{product.plink}</Button>
));

        
return(
 <div>
  {productsLinkResul}
</div>)
```